# Getting a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable when using a list of strings

Tags: python, data-cleaning, difflib

Im trying to get the closest match between two lists of strings (`listA` and `listB`) to create a `listC`.

The purpose for that is because I have to clean a dataframe that has one column of strings which each string represent a fruit which some entries has spelling mistakes that I need to fix.

The actual column that I want to fix is called test:

```
print(test)
```

Output:

```
0             lychee
1         strawberry
2          nectarine
3             lychee
4             lychee
5             banana
6          raspberry
7            loga!!n
....
37497          grape
37498          apple
37499      rockmelon
Name: fruit_ate, Length: 37500, dtype: object
```

Then I converted the test column into a list called `newTest` and I created a list of fruits with the correct names:

```
newTest = list(test)

fruits = ['lychee',
      'strawberry',
      'nectarine',
      'banana',
      'raspberry',
      'kiwi',
      'apple',
      'durian',
      'pear',
      'logan',
      'jackfruit',
      'grape',
      'peach',
      'watermelon',
      'rockmelon',
      'orange']
```

I created a for loop that goes through `newList` and get each element and returns me the closest match in fruits list. However, as I thought it would be easier to try to fix a small list first than just after my code works I could use it to fix the `newTest` list.

So I created these `listA` and `listB`.
I copied some of these values of test column into the `listB`, and I created `listA` with values of the list fruits.

The way I managed to do that was:

```
listA = ['apple', 'banana', 'coco', 'grape', 'pear']
listB = ['ba88tana', 'peeaar', 'apple', 'ggra))pe']
listC = []

for i in listB:
    listC.append(diff.get_close_matches(i, fruits, n=1, cutoff=0.5))

output: [['banana'], ['pear'], ['apple'], ['grape']]
```

When I run this it works fine, but if I apply the same algorithm to my `newTest` list and fruits list it doesn't work, it says:  `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

If someone knows how to fix it or another way that I could do this it would be very helpful.

Comment: What is the value of `newTest`?

Comment: oh, it was supposed to be listB, I forgot to change that. Sorry :/

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect the data in the except suite.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the entire code I would guess that newTest is a float when you are using it with your data?

Or that the line:

```
listC.append(diff.get_close_matches(i, fruits, n=1, cutoff=0.5))
```

The function diff may be recieving a float instead of a string, for example

```
diff.get_close_matches(32, text, n=1, cutoff=.5)
```

Instead of:

```
diff.get_close_matches('32', text, n=1, cutoff=.5)
```

This may be the case if your data is floats and not strings.

```
for i in newTest:
    diff.get_close_matches(str(i), text, n=1, cutoff=.5)
```

Posting relevant parts of the actual test would aid in diagnosis.

Comment: I added more details to clarify what I am trying to do. The cutoff argument is just how close the match needs to be, so I don't think this is the problem. Specially because I took it of to check and it gave me the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

## Dependencies

```
pip install editdistance
```

## code (closest.py)

```
import editdistance
listA = ['apple', 'banana', 'coco', 'grape', 'pear']
listB = ['ba88tana', 'peeaar', 'apple', 'ggra))pe']
listC = []

for i in listB:
    res = None
    distance = len(i)+1
    for j in listA:
        diff = editdistance.eval(i, j)
        if diff < distance:
            distance = diff
            res = j
    listC.append(res)

print listC
```

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: I tried to install editdistance and run this chunk but didn't work as well. It says : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'editdistance'

Comment: python2.x
`pip install editdistance`
for python3
`pip3 install editdistance`